# Ionic "ion-button' is not a known element:" How do I fix this?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have imported { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular'; and added schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] to my component.module.ts file, but am still getting the

"'ion-button' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message." Error.

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormComponentComponent } from './form-component/form-component.component';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [FormComponentComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class FormModule { }
```

Comment: What version of Ionic?

Comment: "@ionic/angular": "^5.3.2"

Comment: You should not have to add any schemas for Angular to recognize ionic elements. That's all taken care of by importing `IonicModule`. Have you imported `IonicModule` in your `app.module.ts` as `IonicModule.forRoot()`?

Comment: Yes, I’ve already imported IonicModule in my app.module.ts file. Not sure why it’s not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button ion-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

this will work

Comment: By using this, I no longer get the error, however the Ionic component doesn't render. I just get a normal button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
IonicModule.forRoot()
```

to your imports. not just

```
IonicModule
```